# R String split by spaces

Tags: r, split, apply

I have a dataframe containing 2 columns, of which one of them is a string that contain spaces. I have used strsplit to split this string into character tokens based on spaces. I defined a function for that (split), which I want to apply on the entire data frame:

```
split <- function (str) strsplit(str, "\\s+")[[1]]
data.frame(raw_rt_data, apply(raw_rt_data$stimulusitem1,2, split) )
```

Here is more info about my dataframe :

```
str(raw_rt_data)
'data.frame':   5372 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ stimulusitem1: Factor w/ 4313 levels "ABILITY    TAX",..: 2483 3645 1339 2455 2769 3033 3998 2712 1313 250 ...
 $ latency      : int  4051 1266 2145 2959 1086 2956 3814 4924 4771 2654 ...
> head(raw_rt_data)
         stimulusitem1 latency
1    MORNING    BUBBLE    4051
2        SYSTEM    MEN    1266
3       FRIEND    PAIN    2145
4     MOMMY    TINYURL    2959
5 PEACE    INFORMATION    1086
6    PUBLIC     SCRITS    2956
```

The problem is that executing the above code yields an error:

```
Error in apply(raw_rt_data$stimulusitem1, 2, split) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

What am I doing wrong? The desired result should be 2 new added columns: one containing the first token and the other one containing the 2nd token.
Any help appreciated

Comment: Your error relates to trying to use `apply` (which requires a matrix/array) on a vector extracted from a data.frame (using `$`). You're also going to encounter a problem due to the fact that `stimulusitem1` is a factor, not a character vector.

Comment: Just a tip--`split` is already an R function so you might consider using a different name for your function!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to split `stimulusitem1 ` into two columns?

Comment: If so, you could maybe try `library(tidyr) ; separate(raw_rt_data, stimulusitem1, c("V1", "V2"))`